# There is an actual working SSL MITM nowadays?

Tags: tls, penetration-test, man-in-the-middle

It's been a while since SSLstrip is deprecated and I see no more options for SSL mitm because of **OSCP/HSTS and browser counter measures**.. Is SSL so unbreakable to common sys admins?

As the owner of the network I want to be sure what passes through my gateway but in means of data, i.e. not just that IP:PORT is connecting via 443 to this HTTPS site..

Even the last known vulnerability such as NTP Skimming attack requirese many aspects that most modern operative systems "fixed" or are hard to replicate in a real scenario..

Have you tried\Do you have any(recent & working) PoC of defeating SSL via Transparent Proxy/Proxy on your own gateway? (Please don't tell me about sslstrip or copy  from google)

Comment: Bluecoat etc offer this for enterprises.

Comment: @AndyBoura: While SSL interception in the firewall is in principle MITM it is not considered an attack because it works only in consent with the user (or the company which uses the firewall) because they need to install the proxy CA of the firewall. Therefore I would not call it "defeating SSL" or breaking it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I put as comment rather than answer as I figured it may help...

Answer (score 1):

> I see no more options for SSL mitm  ...

SSL man in the middle is still easy if some vendors install extra trusted root certificates on their system and include the private key. As example see [Superfish](https://superfish.tlsfun.de/) and [eDellRoot](https://blog.hboeck.de/archives/876-Superfish-2.0-Dangerous-Certificate-on-Dell-Laptops-breaks-encrypted-HTTPS-Connections.html).

MITM is also possible if you know the private key of the site since the same key is shared with 1000s of other devices, see [Nine percent of HTTPS hosts on the web "share the same private keys"](http://www.scmagazine.com/nine-percent-of-https-hosts-on-the-web-share-the-same-private-keys/article/456385/).

And of course MITM is possible if CA issue certificates for domains without authorization, typically done by local sub-CA's inside firewalls as can be seen [here](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/04/google-chrome-will-banish-chinese-certificate-authority-for-breach-of-trust/) and [here](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2486614/security0/french-intermediate-certificate-authority-issues-rogue-certs-for-google-domains.html).

Apart from that: the technologies to defeat sslstrip etc not only have to be available but they have to be used:

- Certificate revocation is not checked properly by Chrome because they check only the certificate [they consider important](https://www.grc.com/revocation/crlsets.htm).
- [HSTS is implemented](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stricttransportsecurity) in all current browsers (even IE11 got it recently) but not in all browsers which are actually in use.
- HSTS is only used [for few sites](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/ce-hsts/all/all).
- HSTS does not protect if the attacker manages to get an alternative certificate (see above). Only HPKP protects against this but this feature is [not implemented by IE, Edge and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#search=hpkp).

> As the owner of the network I want to be sure what passes through my gateway but in means of data, i.e. not just that IP:PORT is connecting via 443 to this HTTPS site..

As the owner of the network you don't need to attack SSL but you can use SSL interception most enterprise level firewalls (and even the free squid proxy) offer. Of course in this case the necessary proxy CA needs to be installed at the clients.